# Scene Dock in Apple's Date Cell Example?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I am looking at Apple's Date Cell ([Date Cell Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html)) example project and I have a question about the **Scene Dock** in **MyTableViewController**. How come there are items extra items in the scene (Like **Picker** and **Done**) that are next to **First Responder**, **Exit**, and **My Table View Controller**? How can this be done? Also, how is this helpful?

This image shows the Scene Dock that I am referring to. Don't mind the titles, I renamed the project.

[image: Scene Dock]

This image shows the Scene Outline for **MyTableViewController**, where the **Picker** and **Done Button** are shown next to the **My Table View Controller, First Responder, and Exit** and not within **My Table View Controller**.

[image: Scene Outline]

This image shows an expanded outline for **My Table View Controller** where the **Picker** object is found also. But not **Done Button** is nowhere to be found inside **My Table View Controller**.

[image: Expanded Scene Outline]

This image shows the code to connect to **Picker** and **Done Button** There is nothing special to this.

[image: Code for Picker and Done Button]

Answer (score 1):

When I delete UIDatePicker in the scene of the controller (not in the cell), the inline DatePicker still works.

I think this sample is meant to support iOS 6.1 or earlier, to reveal the UIDatePicker as an external slide-in view, so it needs to be in the controller for IBOutlet connection.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `MyTableViewController` should not be of type `UITableViewController` but its superclass `UIViewController`. This is normally necessary because `UITableViewController` has by definition its main `view` property set to the table view. It is then difficult to place other views into this view.

With a `UIViewController`, however, you can add any number of views. This is necessary in this case to accommodate the button and picker. The table view controller functionality can still be achieved by manually adding the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols and overriding the appropriate methods.

However, Apple here shows that it is possible by placing the other views on the same level as the main `view`, the table view. This is admittedly quite confusing. I usually prefer adding non-standard views as subviews to the `view` of a plain `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag things like picker views from the library to the scene dock to add them there.

As to the utility of doing this, I have no idea what that would be.

In this case I think that the picker and done button are left over from the writers of the code experimenting with ideas and forgetting to delete them. To verify that just delete the picker view and done button and see if everything still works.